# Entity Framework EDMX Invalid Multiplicity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, multiplicity

I seem to be having trouble with database first multiplicity within the design.
I am using EF v5.0

I have two db entities with the following (psuedo classes for example):

```
entity {
    long Id; //PK
    bool myProp;
}

entity_detail {
    long entityID; //FK to entity.Id
    string name;
    datetime entered;
}
```

When I update the model from the database it correctly generates these classes in the .tt, however, it puts the `entity_detail` into an `ICollection<entity_detail>` in the `entity` class.

This is due to the multiplicity, when I change the multiplicity from `Many (*)` to `Zero or One (0..1)` within the EDMX, it will error out and force me to use `Many (*)`

The issue with this scenario is that the `entity_detail` should **ONLY** be generated if `myProp` is set to *false* (to avoid redundant data in db)

Thus being a 0..1, any idea on how to set this up from the database perspective to get the EDMX to update it to 0..1 on the entity end and 1 on the entity_detail end?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A 0..1 relationship would involve a nullable entity detail ID  inside entity.

Comment: @StevePy Why would you need an entity_detail entity at all if it is not required by the dependent? For example in codefirst you are able to do  modelBuilder.Entity<entity>().HasOptional(e => e.entity_detail).WithRequired(e => e.entity);

Comment: Yes, and that should result in a nullable child ID and associated navigation property in the parent entity. The nullable FK means this parent either has 1 child, or 0 child. A collection would be HasMany().WithRequired() and EF allows 0 or many children. (any attempt to limit it to 0..1 has to be done in code.) A DB FK controlled by the child forms 1-many, there's no way to restrict that no two children can refer to the same parent.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for the answer, the correct setup was to make the foreign key (`entityID`) column on the `entity_detail` object also a *primary key*.

This way it would be unique but only be required if it exists (`0..1`)

Hope this helps!